# Atajos teclado Oracle Sql Developer 18.3 comentar , maximizar/minimizar

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

he estado probando maneras y no encuentro manera en Oracle SQL Developer 18.3 para encontrar atajo de teclado para maximizar/minimizar la ventana de trabajo o los resultados de la consulta según cual esté activa así como comentar/descomentar lineas en la Hoja de Trabajo (por ejemplo quiero comentar un select no poniendo -- sino con el atajo de teclado que me ponga -- o /* ).

Para lo de comentar/descomentar he probado con el atajo de teclado Ctrl+/ y no me funciona (que lo he visto por algún lado en internet)

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que tienes Windows, pero de no ser el caso ten en cuenta que para MAC por ejemplo los comandos cambian (los comentarios sería cmd + option + /).

Si tienes Windows y los atajos no te estan funcionando bien, te aconsejo que vayas a Tools -> Preferences -> Shortcut Keys y eches un vistazo a la configuración. Te dejo este [enlace](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/11/keyboard-shortcuts-in-oracle-sql-developer/) que se explaya algo más con este tema por si te lo quieres mirar.

Un saludo

Comment: Hola, gracias ya había visto esa web y la verdad que no tengo claro si hay esa opción en los atajos de teclado, yo al menos no la he encontrado.

Answer (score 0):

1. En *Preferences > Shortcut Keys* busca por la palabra `Comments`
2. Selecciona `Toggle Multiline Comments`
3. Introduce en *New Shortcut* la combinación de teclas que desees (Ej. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd>)
4. Si el campo *Conficts* se mantiene vacío presiona el botón *Assign*.